# Letters , characters missing!

Tags: 14.04

Yesterday I was trying to install **Cairo dock and docky** ,after some hours removed them .

Now what happening is the whole Ubuntu is not showing anything as before , like when i right click on desktop it shows some letters and nothing else , could not take its screen short. So I am providing the screenshot of Firefox tab as below-

[image: here]

The same thing is happening everywhere like askubuntu tool tips, everywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened on my fiancée's laptop with Ubuntu 14.10.  I asked her to reboot and the problem went away.  The problem has not reappeared, at least not yet.  I have rebooted 30 times in a row and the problem has not reappeared.
If you face this problem again, then please file a bug report with the command ubuntu-bug.  I will do the same.  Do not worry about we filing duplicate reports, that is the way Ubuntu prefers.  Do not add your report as a comment on another bug report (avoid "me too").